# Why doesn't Jest.useFakeTimers work in beforeAll blocks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, settimeout

I wanted to mock timeout functions globally so I added a call to `jest.useFakeTimers` in a `beforeAll` block. When I ran my tests, `jest.advanceTimersByTime` didn't execute the scheduled code. I used spies to confirm that the mock was indeed being called. I noticed however, that if I moved the `jest.advanceTimersByTime` call into the test function, or into a `beforeEach` block, it worked.

Here's a simple example that reproduces the problem.

```
describe('test', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Only beforeEach block works, NOT beforeAll
        jest.useFakeTimers();
    })

    it('setTimeout calls callback', () => {
        const callback = jest.fn();

        setTimeout(() => {
            callback()
        }, 3000);

        expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);

        expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })

})
```

I didn't see anything in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) that explains this. I'm using Jest 26.6.2.

Comment: The example code you provided passes for me. It also passed when I change `beforeEach` to `beforeAll`. Is there some other way to reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check your jest setup file(like `setupFilesAfterEnv` config). Say, If I put those codes in the setup file, then it will run into the problem you said above:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  // reset to real timers
  jest.useRealTimers();
})
```

Because as default behavior, `beforeEach`'s callback is always executed after `beforeAll`'s, even if it is defined before `beforeAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `jest.useFakeTimers` in the documentation replaces setTimeout in product code, not within the test code.